# Read Serial Port data from web application

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, serial-port

How my web application read data from client's serial port? 
Solution that in my mind:

Create windows service and installed on client machine which reads data of client's serial port. Than create WCF service which gets data from windows service that is installed on client machine. Than my web application get data from WCF web service.

Questions:

How windows service returns value ? Is there any mechanism OR built-in libraries ?
How WCF communicates with windows service??

Problem Statement:
Weight machine is attached with client's serial port which sends weight on serial port, from web application i want serial port's data to display on web page..

Comment: What if the client is behind a firewall or router how will you connect to a web service on the client machine? This seems like a job for a local application not a web application.

Comment: Can we assume that you have a unique identifier for the particular client logged on to the site? I just want to clarify how sure you can be which online client relates to which specific local machine/service.

Comment: @Ashigore; Thanks for the consideration.. Yes this is local web application running on local server..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can my web app communicate with serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737198/how-can-my-web-app-communicate-with-serial-port)